# Где взять пример логов postfix?

Tags: postfix

Здравствуйте, нужно написать некий парсер для логов postfix. Можно ли как-то получить пример логфайла, как я уже понял это

```
var/log/mail.log
```

не заморачиваясь с установкой и настройкой почтового сервера у себя на копьютере?

Может ли кто-то поделиться таковым?

Comment: [Log Examples For Postfix](http://ossec-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/log_samples/email/postfix.html)

Comment: Вы это имели ввиду? http://www.gentoo.ru/node/3855

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade 
мне дали задачу написать парсер для логов, который бы находил случаи ошибок / не отправок ,если я не ошибаюсь это bounce называется, и сообщал бы о них. 
Буду очень благодарен, если Вы укажите файл подходящий для этого

Answer (score 0, accepted):

больше всего цитат из логов можно найти, скорее всего, в архивах почтовых рассылок, посвящённых этой программе.

вот список архивов рассылок, опубликованный непосредственно на сайте postfix.org: http://www.postfix.org/lists.html#online

---

ну, и, конечно, не стоит «сбрасывать со счетов» и «первоисточник» — саму программу postfix, в исходниках которой и содержатся все эти сообщения.

Comment: А где взять файл содержащий что-то вроде 

5. Jan 2 20:31:17 tmcent01 postfix/local[27450]: B58C4330038: to=<root@tmcent01.training5.tm>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=local, delay=9.7, delays=9.6/0.03/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)

Но в большем количестве?

Comment: создайте любым подходящим образом. вручную или скриптом/программой.

Comment: разве это не требует развертывания сервера? Прошу прощения за глупые вопросы

Comment: я думаю, для создания файла прекрасно подойдёт и то устройство, которым вы в данный момент пользуетесь при общении со мной.